# Ruby/Rails - Using a symbol or string to define model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
if params[:reviewable_type] == 'Offer'

        reviewable = Offer.find(params[:reviewable_id])

    elsif params[:reviewable_type] == 'Request'

        reviewable = Request.find(params[:reviewable_id])

end
```

Can I simplify this by doing something like `params[:reviewable_type].find(params[:reviewable_id])`, essentially using the string contained in the param as the name of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize).

However, you really shouldn't just blindly allow users to instantiate instances of arbitrary classes. You should always check to see whether the incoming param contains one of your expected classes with a white-list:

```
if %w(Offer Request).include?(params[:reviewable_type])
  reviewable = params[:reviewable_type].constantize.find(params[:reviewable_id])
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. And thanks for the security tip.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
params[:reviewable_type].constantize.find(params[:reviewable_id])
```

But for security reasons I advise not to do this (Hint: guess you find something like `User` in the `params[:reviewable_type]`).

At least you should do something like this:

```
if ['Offer', 'Request'].include?(params[:reviewable_type])
  params[:reviewable_type].constantize.find(params[:reviewable_id])
end
```